# adobe air multi device communication

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, air

How does adobe air applications (flash as3) talk to each other?

For example im building an 1 server app that display data to the LCD Screen in realtime  with 4 slave controller app that can update the data on the server.

One thing that comes in mind is building a mysql database and using php in each client via web browser, and then the server app continuously refreshes for new data.

But setting up a web server (WAMP) is a tedious task for my client to do. I wanted to give them 1 file, presumably adobe air installer, and then they can install and fired the app. or maybe if they want to have slave controller, i can give the 1 more file to be installed in each device.

For that i need a air to air app that communicate to each other, with the server app handling the data. So the questions are:

- Does air have its own database handler?
- How can i connect each controller to the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, AIR [does have SQL engine](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html).
2. You can use [sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) to transfer data between local AIR apps and the server.